# ECS Fargate docker internal networking with service discovery not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, service-discovery

I am running a few microservices in ECS running on Fargate. I need these docker containers to be able to communicate between each other. Right now both containers are simply running NGINX to get a proof of concept up and running.

I have setup a private DNS namespace and created a service for each docker container e.g service1.local and service2.local

I then created the ECS services and linked the service discovery, each ECS service now has the `.local` namespace attached.

Right now both ECS services are in a public subnet with public IP's and are reachable individually. However reach service B via service A's IP is not possible i.e. the two containers cannot communicate with each other.

I get the following error `service1.local could not be resolved (5: Operation refused)`.

I attached an EC2 instance to the same VPC and subnets and was able to ping each service via `service1.local`, `service2.local` curl them etc so so service discovery is working as expected in this situation.

Right now security groups allow traffic from all ports and all IPs (just whilst testing)

Below is a barebones copy of my NGIX config for service1

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    resolver ${PRIVATE_DNS_RESOLVER} valid=10s;
    set $serverHost http://service2.local:8000;

    location /status {
        access_log off;
        add_header 'Content-Type' 'application/json';
        return 200 '{"status":"OK"}';
    }

    # Proxy to server container
    location /api {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect   off;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass $serverHost$request_uri;
    }

    # Route for client
    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    # Route all errors back to index.html for react router to handle
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

Hitting the public IP of this service followed by `/api` is what should proxy to the second service via `service2.local`

tl;dr

Both containers are accessible via public IPs.
Both containers are accessible from within the ups using the service discover private name space
Container one cannot resolve the hostname of container2
The CPC has dns hostnames enabled

The resolver here is one of the NS records from the private namespace. Setting it to `127.0.0.1` or `127.0.0.11` gave the same error.

Comment: Why are you setting a specific DNS resolver address at all? Since the DNS resolution worked on the EC2 instance you tested with, then I'm pretty sure the entire problem is just that you have overridden the default VPC DNS resolver with some other resolver address.

Comment: @MarkB without the resolver I get the following error from NGINX 

`no resolver defined to resolve service2.local`

Comment: Try using the DNS resolver that is attached to your VPC. That is what the EC2 instance used, and that is the server that gets updated when you attach a Route53 private zone to the VPC. The IP address of the VPC resolver is your base VPC address plus 2: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-dns.html So if your VPC starts with `10.0.0.0` then the DNS server is `10.0.0.2`. I'm not sure what is going on that Nginx isn't using that by default.

Comment: @MarkB That was it! Thank you. I also do not understand why docker wasn't picking this up automatically.